# Javascript is not working outside the html document

Tags: javascript, html

I know there are a lot of topics out there about this problem, but I couldn't find any help and I get really frustrated...

So, I'm trying to use an external javascript into my HTML document and it doesn't work. I don't want to insert any script directly into the HTML document, but to use an external one. I tried to insert it between the "head" tags at the top of the document. Not working. Then I moved the "script" tags right above the "/body" tag, so at the very bottom of my body section. Still not working. Here is the code:

```js
var imagesArray = ["images/1.jpg","images/2.jpg","images/3.jpg","images/4.jpg"];
var index = 0;
var image = document.getElementById("image");

var next = document.getElementById("next");
var prev = document.getElementById("prev");

next.addEventListener("click", change(1));
prev.addEventListener("click", change(-1));

function change(x) {
 index += x;

 if (index === 4)
  index = 0;
 
 if (index === -1)
  index = 3;

 image.src = imagesArray[index];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Site</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  #image {
   width: 700px;
  }

  #slideshow div {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   cursor: pointer;
  }

  #next {
   background-color: blue;
  }

  #prev {
   background-color: red;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slideshow">
 <img src="images/1.jpg" id="image">

 <div id="prev"></div>
 
 <div id="next"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

By the way, this is a simple slideshow that I want to make. With a "next" and "prev" button to cycle through the images.

Comment: check your browsers developer tools console, you'll see that prev/next is causing errors. This is because they are null, because the HTML hasn't loaded before the javascript is executing - either move your `script` to the bottom of `body`, or use whatever technique you know to wait for "document ready" before trying to access the DOM - eg wait for document `DOMContentLoaded` event

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
next.addEventListener("click", change(1));
prev.addEventListener("click", change(-1));
```

with:

```
next.addEventListener("click", function(){ change(1); });
prev.addEventListener("click", function(){ change(-1); });
```

`addEventListener` takes function as second argument. What you're passing is some value generated by the function `change`. By passing `function(){ ... }` you're creating anonymous function which will be executed every time event is triggered.

Comment: This is also a correct answer, albeit a little light on the details. My answer is effectively the same, but requires [ECMAScript 5 Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es5)... which is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

The document is getting the Javascript just fine, but you can't pass arguments when defining an event listener like that. Instead of what you expect, it executes `change(1)` when you define the event listener for `next` and `change(-1)` when you define the event listener for `prev`.

Then, the event handler for each of the buttons is set to the return value of the already executed functions. The functions don't return anything, so that becomes `undefined`

You can confirm this by adding a `console.log()` line to your `change()` function and looking at your browser's console when you load the page and when you click the button.

So, it executes them right away and nothing happens when you click the buttons.

You need to [*bind*](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/function/bind) the argument to the event listener like this:

```
next.addEventListener("click", change.bind(null, 1));
prev.addEventListener("click", change.bind(null, -1));
```

**Update**
There was an excellent point made by @jaromanda-x in one of the comments to your question. Your Javascript could potentially run before the document loads. So, it wouldn't be able to find the elements with the IDs "next" and "prev". If you're not using something like jQuery, you'll probably want to put the part of your Javascript that works with elements in the document inside of a [`window.onload`](http://devdocs.io/dom/globaleventhandlers/onload) event handler function.

Comment: And what if I create a function with no arguments? Will I have to do the same? That bind stuff...?

Comment: @Xyntell Nope. Just use the function name without the parentheses. i.e. `next.addEventListener("click", change)`

Answer (score 0):

addEventListener format is

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(){/*code*/}, false);
```

so change it

```
next.addEventListener("click", function(){change(1);},false);
prev.addEventListener("click", function(){change(-1);},false);
```

onclick method also can use

```
element.onclick = function () { /*code */ };
next.onclick    = function () { change(1); };
prev.onclick    = function () { change(-1);};
```